# how to resolve maven test prob?

Tags: maven, geoserver

within a geoserver source installation (`mvn clean install`), an error occured.

```
Tests run: 552, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] GeoServer ......................................... SUCCESS [4.397s]
[INFO] Core Platform Module .............................. SUCCESS [5.694s]
[INFO] Open Web Service Module ........................... SUCCESS [9.344s]
[INFO] Main Module ....................................... SUCCESS [5:45.515s]
[INFO] Web Feature Service Module ........................ SUCCESS [6:30.520s]
[INFO] Web Coverage Service Module ....................... SUCCESS [0.922s]
[INFO] Web Map Service Module ............................ FAILURE [6:37.078s]
[INFO] GeoServer Web Modules ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Core UI Module .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Security Modules ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer JDBC Security Module .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer LDAP Security Module .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Web Coverage Service 1.0 Module ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Web Coverage Service 1.1 Module ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] KML support for GeoServer ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoWebCache (GWC) Module .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] REST Support Module ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] REST Configuration Service Module ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] WMS UI Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GWC UI Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WFS UI Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Demoes Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WCS UI Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Security UI Modules ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Security UI Core Module ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Security UI JDBC Module ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Security UI LDAP Module ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Web Application ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Community Space ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Extensions .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19:16.476s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 02 15:04:31 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 72M/227M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.3:test (default-test) on project wms:
 There are test failures.
```

according to [geoserver instructions](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/quickstart/index.html), it should work.
anyway, i am not experienced with maven and this error is a stumbling block.

any hints how to resolve this error?

Comment: Maven with surefire creates test-reports (under `target/surefire-reports`). Please check if there is any report about the failed tests, and examine the contents (or perhaps post them here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to skip the tests add `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` to your mvn-call like

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

But it would be interesting why the tests failed, so checking the reports is certainly a good idea.

Comment: but this is not the real solution . is it ?